# How to get text values of dropdown attributes for product?

Tags: product-attribute, performance

I need to display on product page 30 attributes which have dropdown values.
Is it possible to load them in couple queries instead of individual query for every attribute?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply apply this logic as a patch to standard Magento functionality to improve performance on product view (requires rewrite of core model):

https://gist.github.com/IvanChepurnyi/6586713

```
/**
 * Optimized version of attribute source options model
 *
 * That allows to preload options once and reuse them instead of doing calls to db all the time
 *
 */
class EcomDev_Optimization_Model_Resource_Attribute_Source_Table
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table
{
    /**
     * List of preloaded options per attribute
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $_preloadedOptions = array();
    /**
     * List of stores where default values already preloaded
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $_preloadedOptionsStores = array();
    /**
     * List of preloaded options for each option id
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $_preloadedOptionHash = array();
    /**
     * Retrieve store options from preloaded hashes
     *
     * @param int $storeId
     * @param int $attributeId
     * @param string $type
     * @return array
     */
    protected static function _getPreloadedOptions($storeId, $attributeId, $type)
    {
        self::_preloadOptions($storeId);
        $key = self::_getCombinedKey($storeId, $attributeId, 'store');
        if (isset(self::$_preloadedOptions[$key])) {
            return self::$_preloadedOptions[$key];
        }
        return array();
    }
    /**
     * Preloads values for option values on the first call
     *
     * @param int $storeId
     */
    protected static function _preloadOptions($storeId)
    {
        if (isset(self::$_preloadedOptionsStores[$storeId])) {
            return;
        }

        self::$_preloadedOptionsStores[$storeId] = true;
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
            ->setPositionOrder('asc')
            ->setStoreFilter($storeId);

        // This one allows to limit selection of options, based on frontend criteria.
        // E.g. if not all the attribute options are needed for the current page
        Mage::dispatchEvent('eav_entity_attribute_source_table_preload_options', array(
            'collection' => $collection,
            'store_id'   => $storeId
        ));

        $options = $collection->getData();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $optionKey = self::_getCombinedKey($storeId, $option['option_id'], 'store');
            $storeKey = self::_getCombinedKey($storeId, $option['attribute_id'], 'store');
            $defaultKey = self::_getCombinedKey($storeId, $option['attribute_id'], 'default');
            self::$_preloadedOptionHash[$optionKey] = $option['value'];
            self::$_preloadedOptions[$storeKey][] = array(
                'value' => $option['option_id'],
                'label' => $option['value']
            );
            self::$_preloadedOptions[$defaultKey][] = array(
                'value' => $option['option_id'],
                'label' => $option['default_value']
            );

        }
    }
    /**
     * Overridden to manipulate options
     *
     * @param bool $withEmpty
     * @param bool $defaultValues
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false)
    {
        $storeId = $this->getAttribute()->getStoreId();
        if (!is_array($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = array();
        }
        if (!is_array($this->_optionsDefault)) {
            $this->_optionsDefault = array();
        }
        if (!isset($this->_options[$storeId])) {
            $this->_options[$storeId] = self::_getPreloadedOptions(
                $storeId,
                $this->getAttribute()->getId(),
                'store'
            );
            $this->_optionsDefault[$storeId] = self::_getPreloadedOptions(
                $storeId,
                $this->getAttribute()->getId(),
                'default'
            );
        }
        $options = ($defaultValues ? $this->_optionsDefault[$storeId] : $this->_options[$storeId]);
        if ($withEmpty) {
            array_unshift($options, array('label' => '', 'value' => ''));
        }
        return $options;
    }
    /**
     * Returns option key for hash generation
     *
     * @param int $storeId
     * @param int $optionId
     * @param string $type
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function _getCombinedKey($storeId, $optionId, $type)
    {
        return $storeId . '|' . $optionId . '|' . $type;
    }
    /**
     * Retrieves option label from preloaded options hash array
     *
     * @param int|string $value
     * @return array|bool|string
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $storeId = $this->getAttribute()->getStoreId();
        $this->_preloadOptions($storeId);
        $isMultiple = false;
        if (strpos($value, ',')) {
            $isMultiple = true;
            $value = explode(',', $value);
        }
        if ($isMultiple) {
            $values = array();
            foreach ($value as $item) {
                $key = self::_getCombinedKey($storeId, $item, 'store');
                if (isset(self::$_preloadedOptionHash[$key])) {
                    $values[] = self::$_preloadedOptionHash[$key];
                }
            }
            return $values;
        }
        $key = self::_getCombinedKey($storeId, $value, 'store');
        if (isset(self::$_preloadedOptionHash[$key])) {
            return self::$_preloadedOptionHash[$key];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```